# Xampp not supporting php Include

Tags: php, xampp

I know this has been discussed a lot throughout the Stackoverflow.

But still I can't make it work for me, I've been searching for hours, no joke.

I always make my index.php page like this:

```
<? include ("header.php");?>

<? if($_REQUEST['p']==''){ include('home.php') }
if($_REQUEST['p']=='atelier'){ include('atelier.php'); }
if($_REQUEST['p']=='quem_somos'){ include('quem_somos.php'); }
if($_REQUEST['p']=='que_criamos'){ include('que_criamos.php'); }
if($_REQUEST['p']=='projetos3d'){ include('projetos3d.php'); }
if($_REQUEST['p']=='noticias'){ include('noticias.php'); }
if($_REQUEST['p']=='localizacao'){ include('localizacao.php'); }
if($_REQUEST['p']=='contactos'){ include('contactos.php'); } ?>

<? include ("footer.php");?>
```

It is supposed to always loads the header and footer.

On page opening it is supposed to load the home.php because there's no request and the menu of the website has links that are requests to other pages.

This always worked for me, I used to work on a ftp server but now I'm using XAMPP for this and it seems like the includes are not working at all.

Is there any file I could go and change some permissions or even better change the way I include the files to be supported on XAMPP?

EDIT: For those asking about how REQUEST works, I have a sample here, it might be easier to understand if you see the menu working: [link](http://gee.pt/)

EDIT 2: By not supporting I mean: it displays a blank page, it doesn't load neither the header/footer nor the pages themselves

EDIT 3: I've enabled short_open_tag and allow_url_include in php.ini, still not working.

EDIT 4: I went to try easyphp and I still got the same problem... I'd rather not move from where I am and keep the XAMPP to find a solution for this.

Comment: Not supporting means ?? You got any error ? Make sure that you turned on the Short Tag in `php.ini`

Comment: suggestion: too many php opening and closing tags when you all have in your code is only php code.

Comment: what $_REQUEST['p'] contains?

Comment: as you say that header and footer are loading then the problem is with your `$_REQUEST` variable it is having no value that matches the condition

Comment: Your XAMPP configuration may not supported `<?` short tag. Did you tried `<?php` full tag?

Comment: @Sourabh sorry I didn't express myself the right way. Nothing is including. Everything works on the server but in XAMPP nothing includes.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen No error, it just shows a blank page.

Comment: Can you turn on the error reporting and see the error ?

Comment: as mentioned by `Nikko` you should check was writing short tags was enabled in XAMPP server

Comment: BTW the right usage is without brackets: include $file.

Comment: @bub it was fine with include function. there is no error in that

Comment: after editing your `php.ini`, restart your apache @White8Tiger

Comment: @Nikko yes I did it.

Comment: write this in your first code line and see what happens. Please write down your error.
`ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`

Comment: @White8Tiger have you tried full tag? is it work?

Comment: @Nikko yes I also tried that before having lunch. I'm back at the office and I'll be going back to work directly in the server, I'm giving up on this. I'm wasting time for nothing. Thank you for the help tho.